# PC shuts down when selecting Sleep

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, sleep, power

I've had this problem from a while now and it is really frustrating.

It all started after I changed my SSD with a new one. The one I had was M.2 SATA and the new one is M.2 NVMe. After changing it, I noticed that whenever I tried putting the PC to sleep, it actually shut down. 
  Of course I started googling the problem, and trust me, I've tried everything: updated my BIOS, Windows is up to date, I've tried changing the power plan, I've tried running the troubleshooter, I've also tried sfc /scannow but it didn't detect any problems, I've updated the IMEI..

What I haven't tried is messing with the BIOS settings, because I'm not even sure what I'm doing there, or what the Power option is. My motherboard is Gigabyte B360M.

I've also done a disk surface test and there were no bad sectors or anything.

I'm not even sure what to do anymore, but it is really annoying. Do you have any ideas, any advice on what this could possibly be?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Five things you should do:

(1) Update BIOS - Use care and make sure the BIOS is for your specific computer.

(2) Check if there is a power management driver and update that.

(3) Get the PC manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all other drivers.

(4) Restart, select the Balanced Power plan and set it to defaults.

(5) Run Windows updates, do a final restart and test.